# Ubuntu Touch : Command to force OTA-13 reinstallation?

Tags: updates, ubuntu-touch

This morning the `OTA-13` update was proposed on my Meizu Pro 5, I was on Wi-Fi I "clicked" on it. The download was fast (~ 250mb), I clicked again on the button to launch the install (and late the reboot) and my screen was stuck on the same screen for 1 hour.

Then the screen closed. I went to my settings and I'm still on `OTA-12`. I tried to force another update, but I'm told that the software is updated.

Now my phone works (that's not the problem) but I can't have the update. Is there a command or manipulation to relaunch update ?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the *Terminal* app on the phone, you can run `sudo system-image-cli -vvvv -b 0` and it should download the image and flash it again. You may need to make sure the app stays in foreground and the screen doesn't blank while you run this, though.

Comment: Hi (and thank you), I've this curious message :') >> AssertionError: Missing destination files: ['/var/lib/system-image/keyring.tar.xz', '/var/lib/system-image/keyring.tar.xz.asc']

Comment: Thank you so much for putting me on the good way : I succeeded with a slightly different command >> sudo SYSTEMIMAGE_PYCURL=1 system-image-cli -vv

Comment: From several threads I heard, that there are some errors often with the Ubuntu Touch's built in system-image-cli command. I prefer the Desktop commands from my answer, so far it's possible. :)

Comment: Well, I have been using system-image-cli on multiple devices for 2.5 years with no real problems with it. It works just fine. If you prefer to wipe all your data every time, that's certainly your prerogative, but please don't perpetuate misinformation as an argument for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

You can 'switch' to the stable channel keeping your personal data and apps by using the ubuntu-device-flash tool or the magic-device-tool. But be carefully because both use recovery and need a persistent USB connection to your Ubuntu Desktop OS.

Comment: OK, if there's no other solution I'll try this tonight; thank you ;)

Comment: This is not quite true. It is not required to flash from fastboot. One can flash from recovery (using the correct recovery image) or with the OS booted (if developer mode is enabled), without erasing user data.

Comment: Okay, my fault. I changed it my answer. I basically wanted to say, that it's a deep touch in the device.