# ssl certificates not recognized on BQ aquaris E4.5

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Recently I have trouble with a number of ssl certificates. Some https sites work (google) and some do not (e.g., Amazon, here.com, conrad.de, Symantec). It appears that the browser on ubuntu touch cannot validate the certificate from Symantec and from GeoTrust.

A colleague of mine has the same problem. Previously these sites worked (certainly mid December last year). Are we the only ones who have these problems? How do I resolve this?

The phone has all updates and the time is set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the information.

I had issues with the command as written above on my BQ Aquaris E5.

Displayed messages like " Missing destination files: ['/var/lib/system-image/keyring.tar.xz', '/var/lib/system-image/keyring.tar.xz.asc']"

Having found [Ubuntu Touch : Command to force OTA-13 reinstallation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827817/ubuntu-touch-command-to-force-ota-13-reinstallation) added "SYSTEMIMAGE_PYCURL=1" to the command as per the comment from https://askubuntu.com/users/597509/danslerush on the OTA issue.

e.g.

```
sudo SYSTEMIMAGE_PYCURL=1 system-image-cli -vvvv --switch ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/bq-aquaris.en
```

This appeared to resolve the certification issues.
Took a while though for the command to complete and do it's reboots, luckily I just had it just put it on mains after low battery.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an exchange on the ubuntu-phone [mailing list](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg23343.html)  this seems to be a regularly occurring problem.

There is a bug filed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/webbrowser-app/+bug/1656551

Steps to resolve:

A. Wait for OTA-15

or

B. Switch your device to the rc-proposed channel, which has a more recent version of oxide.

To do so:

1. Install the Terminal app from the store (or if you have enabled developer mode, you can use the phablet-shell tool over USB connection).

   If using Terminal app on the phone, you may need to disable screen locking Battery Settings first, as if the screen locks, the Terminal app (and its child processes) will be stopped.
2. Run `sudo system-image-cli -vvvv --switch ubuntu-touch/rc-proposed/bq-aquaris.en`

Instructions on how to switch channels are taken from another question on ask Ubuntu. It seems that these instructions didn't work for everyone - and some people posted their working alternatives

References :

[How to switch channels](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873328/ssl-certificates-not-recognized-on-bq-aquaris-e4-5)

[Info about channels and their names](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/image-channels/)