# Ubuntu Touch(OTA-14) Amazon.de App is blank

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Recently, when I launching the app Amazon.de, the URL bar and a white screen are displayed. When I press the Refresh button, the app closes. What can I do?
A new installation did not solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: Is that the only website that you've noticed that behavior with?

Comment: Only the Amazon.de Web App makes problems. All other Web Apps work fine. I have not made any changes at the system.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might be the same issue as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/873328/ssl-certificates-not-recognized-on-bq-aquaris-e4-5/873356#873356)

I gave an answer there but tldr: it's an issue with oxide. To solve it you can wait for OTA-15 or switch to the rc-proposed channel - see link above for details.